# Does 'grant select' without 'grant option' revoke previous 'grant option'?

Tags: mysql

Let's take an example:

```
us1: GRANT SELECT ON table to us2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
us2: GRANT SELECT ON table to us3 WITH GRANT OPTION;
us3: GRANT SELECT ON table to us2;
```

Does us2 have the GRANT option now?
I couldn't find any info about that if GRANT revokes previous permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All permission grants are positive edits, so it does not revoke any grants at all. If it would not work like that, granting rights would become nearly impossible:

For example:

```
 GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO user1
```

And then

```
 GRANT ALL ON db.abc TO user1
```

Would then only result in the last grant, making it impossible for you to build elaborate grants.